# C# overriding method

Tags: c#

I need help with overriding method `IEnumerator<T>`. I want to have a dictionary class that during enumeration will return only elements, like dictionary.Values. It work in foreach, I suggest that because foreach use `IEnumerator` instead of `IEnumerator<T>`, but LINQ methods not work over instances of my class. If I try call linq method I get Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type.  'Where' not found.

```
public abstract class SpecialDictionary : Dictionary<TKey, MyClass>, IEnumerable<MyClass>
{
    public Add(MaClass item)
    {
        Add(item.Id, item); 
    }

    new public IEnumerator<MyClass> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.Values.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I need collection of items with fast access to element by id. All elements have Guid id. This seemed like a good idea for me, but I welcome your suggestions of this solutions.

Comment: Can you not just return `this.Values` and I believe your return type should be `IEnumerable<MyClass>`

Comment: _"but LINQ methods not work"_ - always describe what does (not) happen, error messages etc. Don't make us guess.

Comment: Remove the `new` before GetEnumerator() and then read the warining, that's the start of your trail.

Comment: T. Kiley: Why not? 

Henk Holterman: Withnout new keyword I try before. It is not work anyway.

Comment: @Lenny what Henk is hinting at is that the error message is suggestive of the underlying issue: the fact that these is already a `GetEnumerator()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `SpecialDictionary` now implements both `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Guid,MyClass>>` and `IEnumerable<MyClass>`. Because of this ambiguity, LINQ is unable to choose between these two options, and chooses neither. The extension methods still work, but require explicit type parameters:

```
MyClass item = dict.First<MyClass>();
```

and equally:

```
KeyValuePair<Guid, MyClass> pair = dict.First<KeyValuePair<Guid, MyClass>>();
```

LINQ, however, will not allow you to add explicit type parameters, so will not work. My advice: don't do that. If the user wants to work over the values, let them do so via `.Values`.

---

Here's an example of encapsulation:

```
public class SpecialDictionary : IEnumerable<MyClass>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Guid, MyClass> inner = new Dictionary<Guid, MyClass>();
    public void Add(MyClass item)
    {
        inner.Add(item.Id, item);
    }

    public MyClass this[Guid id]
    {
        get { return inner[id]; }
        set { inner[id] = value; }
    }
    public bool TryGetValue(Guid id, out MyClass value)
    {
        return inner.TryGetValue(id, out value);
    }
    public IEnumerator<MyClass> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return inner.Values.GetEnumerator();
    }
    public int Count { get { return inner.Count; } }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. there is really no way to use this? I do not always use them .Value

Comment: @Lenny the other thing to do would be to *encapsulate* the dictionary instead of inheriting it. Then the type only implements one `IEnumerable<T>` API.

Comment: @Lenny I added a full encapsulation example that works with LINQ

Comment: The implementation of the encapsulation could also be done with the `System.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection` class. Is there a reason you do not mention it?

Comment: @JeanHominal `KeyedCollection` is a very different model (it preserves order, for example, and has different memory etc profile); the OP was modelling a dictionary, so I illustrated a dictionary. A `KeyedCollection` is not the same thing. It really comes down to what the OP had in the question.